# How to write a test case?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit, sentestingkit

In my application, I have two text fields for entering User-name and Password. I need to write test case for checking Password field is not empty. I Set Up the testing environment and I know how to call methods from testing class, but I don't know how to write test case. Please help me to write a test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with a test that looks something like this:

```
@implementation LoginViewTests

- (void)testPasswordFieldIsNotEmpty {
    LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    //any other setup such as calling -viewDidLoad
    STAssertTrue([loginView.passwordField.text length] > 0, @"The field should not be empty");
    [loginView release]; //unless you're using ARC
}

@end
```

Now, does that pass (indeed does it even build)? If not, make the necessary changes to your code.

Comment: Slightly OT, but if you're instantiating a UIViewController subclass in a test like this, do you need to call loadView (assuming it's not loading from a xib)?

Comment: @WillPragnell: depends what you need to test.

Comment: @Graham Lee If I did code like -(void)getLoginCredentials{  if([passwordField.text length]){    //write code   } else { UIAlertView *aler= //-alloc init- and [alert show]; } what will happen does the test fail? I dont understand the terminology "Test fail", "test success" and "failing test cases", "succeeding test cases" could you please explain?

Comment: @GrahamLee sure. What I should of asked was: "Does OCUnit call loadView for you?". The answer being No. to be honest had I thought of it in that wording I probably would have realised that it was obvious!

Comment: @rakeshNS A test "passes" if all of the assertions in the test method are satisfied. It "fails" if any of them is not met. So the test I've described will pass if, once you've set up the view controller, the password field is not empty.

Comment: @GrahamLee When I tested, the test failed because initially the password field was empty and during test, the application exited immediately after launch so that I could not enter any input. I think I cant write test case that will validate during its Run

Comment: I don't understand. You said you expect the password field to not be empty, and the test is failing because the password field is empty. That sounds like expected behaviour.

Comment: @WillPragnell coming very late to this reply: the test does nothing any more or less magical than would happen in an app. If you try to access `.view`, then `-loadView` and `-viewDidLoad` will be called. If you don't, they aren't…you could still do it yourself though.